# Solr Facet , how exclude only main query?

Tags: solr

My core solr "catalog" have theses field :

```
"category":yyyyy
"s_brand":zzzzz
"visibilty":hhhhh
"color":wwww
```

The start, that i call "main query", is :

```
q=category:computer
```

So , i want only computer on my result.

Then, i set facet to s_brand:
facet.field=s_brand&facet=on&q=category:computer

Here, i have list of computer and facet "s_brand" with constraint like :

```
s_brand :
ACER (5)
APPLE(10)
HP(4)
BANG&OLUFSEN(0)
ADIDAS(0)
REEBOK(0)
```

This list include all brand, not only brand they match main query  category:computer.

I set facet s_marque with minCount(1) :

```
s_brand :
ACER (5)
APPLE(10)
HP(4)
```

It's good. BUT !!

Now i will add other facet like color

```
s_brand :
   ACER (5)
   APPLE(11)
   HP(4)

color:
   PINK(7)
   BLUE(13)
```

Then, i filterquery ( always with mainquery category:computer) on brand

```
fq=brand:ACER
```

i have :

```
brand:
  ACER(5)
color:
  PINK(2)
  BLUE(3)
```

I want keep the other constraint ( about ux), so i exclude filter from facet.

```
fq={!tag=dt}brand:ACER&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt}brand
```

Results:

```
s_brand :
   ACER (5)
   APPLE(11)
   HP(4)

color:
   PINK(7)
   BLUE(13)
```

So, i have all facet who respect my main query but the count don't follow my filter query.

How i can get facet:
1 respect my main query  ( only category computer)
2 who return all facet who respect this main query
3 but return count after filterquery

Like that :

```
s_brand :
   ACER (5)
   APPLE(0)
   HP(0)

color:
   PINK(2)
   BLUE(3)
```

Edit : My solutions actually 11/10/2019:

1. Two facets for same field. One exclude / one no exclude.  Then i manage result with php.  I don't like but work.
2. I finds that : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/json-facet-api.html 
   About bucket and sub facets ( nested facets)
   Results are really special and we need to hard process them behind..  but it's really strong seems to be the good way.

Comment: Ho, I face the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: i advice to read some doc about my solution 2.